# Consistent random colour highlights

Tags: perl

In a table I have columns with to and from dates, I highlight overlaps between rows taking into account the periods, this is done exhaustively in nested loops. This is not the issue.
I need the same colour for the rows that overlap.

```
sub highlight_overlaps {
    my $date_from1;
    my $date_to1;
    my $date_from2;
    my $date_to2;

    my $i = 0;
    my $j = 0;

    for ($i; $i < $#DATE_HOLDER; $i++) {
        $date_from1 = $DATE_HOLDER[$i][0];
        $date_to1   = $DATE_HOLDER[$i][1];

        my $red   = int(rand(65))  + 190;
        my $green = int(rand(290)) - 55;
        my $blue  = int(rand(290)) - 55;

        for ($j=$i+1; $j<=$#DATE_HOLDER; $j++) {
            $date_from2 = $DATE_HOLDER[$j][0];
            $date_to2   = $DATE_HOLDER[$j][1];

            if (($date_from1 le $date_to2   && $date_to1 ge $date_to2) ||
                ($date_from1 le $date_from2 && $date_to1 le $date_to2) ||
                ($date_from1 gt $date_from2 && $date_from1 lt $date_to2)) {

                $tb->setCellStyle($i+2, 6, "background-color:rgb($red,$green,$blue);font-size:9pt");
                $tb->setCellStyle($i+2, 7, "background-color:rgb($red,$green,$blue);font-size:9pt");

                $tb->setCellStyle($j+2, 6, "background-color:rgb($red,$green,$blue);font-size:9pt");
                $tb->setCellStyle($j+2, 7, "background-color:rgb($red,$green,$blue);font-size:9pt");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This works fine if it's just a pair of dates; say:

1) `25-06-2012  27-06-2012`

2) `18-06-2012  29-06-2012`

Will get the same colour

If though I have

0) `26-06-2012  28-06-2012`

1) `25-06-2012  27-06-2012`

2) `18-06-2012  29-06-2012`

0 will get a different colour while 1 & 2 are paired as intended.

When and how to pick colours so that different colours are only applied to different overlaps?

Following up on the first answer; how may I represent overlaps in order to store them in a data structure, so that I can colour them after their detection?

Comment: Do you realize that lt (stringwise less than) isn't actually doing a date comparison?  It does a character by character ascii comparison until the first mismatch, and returns the result of that character match.  E.g. "11-02-2012 01:01:01" lt "22-01-2012 01:01:01" is TRUE.  Based on your date format, if all your test dates were within the same month, you may not have seen this.  Using ISO 8601 will allow for stringwise comparison though.

Comment: Your example date pairs listed above are not ISO 8601, which confuses the issue, since it's implied those are the actual inputs.

Comment: Actual dates or input are irrelevant to my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to compare each interval against **each other interval**, and put them in 'buckets' when they are equal. Now when you compare an interval to a third interval, you put the third in the same bucket as the interval.

Then you print the buckets.

Perl's hash would make for fine buckets.

#### About your overlap detection

There is no overlap if

- date1_to < date2_from OR
- date2_to < date1_from

Or, in Perl:

```
if ($date_to1 lt $date_from2 || $date_to2 lt $date_from1) {
#overlap
}
```

Invert that either using Perl's `unless`, or using de Morgan:

```
if ($date_to1 ge $date_from2 && $date_to2 ge $date_from1) {
#overlap
}
```

Comment: I find it hard to see to which of my 3 conditions you refer to, many ways to represent overlaps and I cant see which one you mean having it written like this. Will give the hash a go

Comment: I was referring to your entire `if`. The 6 conditions can be replaced by 2, imho. But that's just a by-the-by. The bucket thingy is the way to classify sets into subsets.

Comment: Yeah with those two is neater the inner and outer ranges with exact match thrown in as well.

Comment: The hash idea is nice but I can't see how I can implemented - hence undoing my accept would appreciate more detail (this is not some homework assignment btw)

Comment: Well, your specifications are incomplete too. It is clear that if A overlaps B, and B overlaps C, and A overlaps C, you want a set (A,B,C). But what if A overlaps B, B overlaps C, but A does not overlap C? Example: 14-18, 17-20, 19-23. If you want a more complete solution, you'll need a more complete question (specs or tests).

Comment: Thats a good point I'll have to see how other applications handle this. Does this problem have a name, for instance from computer science, and the dates instance is a mere example of it?